# Conversion from ROS timestamp to ISO-8601 time format

Tags: ros, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to convert a ROS timestamp like this:

```
ros::Time stamp = ros::Time::now();
```

to string in ISO-8601 format.

The best resource I was able to google up so far is this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960318/math-to-convert-seconds-since-1970-into-date-and-vice-versa

Is there by any chance any function in ROS I can use instead of coding my own convertor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251966/conversion-from-ros-timestamp-to-iso-8601-time-format/) by [Fairf4x](https://answers.ros.org/users/29048/fairf4x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-01-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something like this should work:

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

boost::posix_time::ptime my_posix_time = ros::Time::now().toBoost();
std::string iso_time_str = boost::posix_time::to_iso_extended_string(my_posix_time)
```

Is it the ISO you are looking for? (Didn't test so please double-check syntax and result)

Reference: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2017-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tested the code and it works as it is.

Later I found out, that the string compliant with ISO-8601 can represent time with [various precision](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Anyway the output I got from the ROS timestamp using the function:

> boost::posix_time::to_iso_extended_string(my_posix_time)

looked like this:

> iso_time_str = 2017-01-17T21:02:40.289279

I needed only seconds so I am happy with the result.
Thank you for quick answer.

---

Originally posted by [Fairf4x](https://answers.ros.org/users/29048/fairf4x/) with karma: 53 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2